# Why do I get 'django core exceptions improperlyconfigured...' when I import from my models?

Tags: python, django

I have had a look through answers regarding this error so my question is specifically why do I get this error when I include the following line?:

```
from teams.models import clubs
```

I don't understand why this import causes the problem.

The traceback is:

```
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 1012, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line
 146, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 46, in __ge
tattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40, in _set
up
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TAB
LESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment
 variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing s
ettings.
```

The full code for 'populate_players.py':

```
import os
import sys
import django
from teams.models import clubs 

club1 = "Arsenal" 
club2 = clubs.objects.get(name = club1);

def add_players(name, position, born, height, weight, nationality, club=club2, active=True):
    # run the script per club

    p = players.objects.get_or_create(name=name, position=position, born=born, height=height, weight=weight, nationality=nationality)
    return p

def populate():
    add_players(name='Calum Chambers',
        position = 'DEF', # list
        born = '2015-01-20',
        height = '1.83',
        weight = '65',
        nationality = 'England'
        ) 

    for p in players.objects.all():
        print p 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting player population script..."
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "epl.settings")
    django.setup()
    from teams.models import players
    populate()
```

And models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class clubs(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    logo = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    manager = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    established = models.IntegerField()
    stadium = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # Fixtures, form, league position?

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name 


class players(models.Model):
    GOALKEEPER = 'GK'
    DEFENDER = 'DEF'
    MIDFIELDER = 'MID'
    FORWARD = 'FWD'
    POSITION_CHOICES = (
        (GOALKEEPER, 'Goalkeeper'),
        (DEFENDER, 'Defender'),
        (MIDFIELDER, 'Midfielder'),
        (FORWARD, 'Forward'),
        )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    club = models.OneToOneField('clubs', related_name= "team")
    position = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=POSITION_CHOICES, default=GOALKEEPER) # GK, Defender, Midfielder, Attacker -  Field for this? 
    born = models.DateField()
    height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
    weight = models.IntegerField() # Field for this?
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=64) # Choices
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # active = current epl player
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Could you also post your models.py?

Comment: Yep, I've just added it into my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling this script locally and not through the django server you need to import/configure the settings before you import e.g. your models:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(DEBUG=True, TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True,
    TEMPLATE_DIRS=('/home/web-apps/myapp', '/home/web-apps/base'))
```

You can find more details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module).

Comment: Did you call it before the line "from teams.models import clubs" ?