# Trying to import models from an app throws an ImproperlyConfigured exception

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-import

I made a small web scraper to fill make all the db entries for my models but when I import my models I'm getting this ImproperlyConfigured exception and I'm not sure why.

My import is as follows

```
from ship_showroom.models import Ship, ShipExternals, ShipInternals, ShipOptionalInternals, ShipOptionalInternalsMilitary, Image
```

The traceback is as follows

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/mdacrim97/eliteDangerous/ship_scraper.py", line 5, in 
> from ship_showroom.models import Ship, ShipExternals, ShipInternals, ShipOptionalInternals, ShipOptionalInternalsMilitary, Image
> File "/home/mdacrim97/eliteDangerous/ship_showroom/models.py", line 4, in 
> class Ship(models.Model):
> File "/home/mdacrim97/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in **new**
> app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
> File "/home/mdacrim97/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
> self.check_apps_ready()
> File "/home/mdacrim97/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
> settings.INSTALLED_APPS
> File "/home/mdacrim97/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 82, in **getattr**
> self._setup(name)
> File "/home/mdacrim97/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 67, in _setup
> % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I'm just starting my Django journey so I have no idea where something is wrong.

It seems odd to me because I can do the exact same import just fine via python manage.py shell but in my web scraper file it does that which is in the same directory as manage.py

I'm really lost any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is perfectly described it https://stackoverflow.com/a/28770524/13615996

Comment: Is your web scraper file a django management command?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/